# Installing WordPress with /wp path leads to redirect loop when index.html redirects to a shopping cart

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress, apache2, too-many-redirects

So on my site, my shopping cart is located at `example.com/zc2`

I use this .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

Redirect /index.html example.com/zc2/
```

So that anyone that lands on `example.com` will be redirected to my shopping cart.

All good, but now if I try and install WordPress at `example.com/wp` then browsers get stuck in a redirect loop.

I am positive it is my badly crafted .htaccess file.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please post your `/wp/.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
>
> Redirect /index.html example.com/zc2/
> ```

*Aside:* I assume this must be a "typo" in your question, but this mod_alias `Redirect` directive is completely invalid (you are missing a protocol from the target URL) - this would break your server with a 500 Internal Server Error - "Redirect to non-URL"!?

Also, `RewriteEngine` (mod_rewrite) and `Redirect` (mod_alias) are unrelated directives from different Apache modules.

> What can I do to fix this?

However, I suspect the "redirect loop" might be caused by a miss-configured WordPress `.htaccess` file in the `/wp` subdirectory. If you are inadvertently rewriting back to the document root, instead of the `/wp` subdirectory, then you'll get a redirect loop.

The `Redirect` directive is also "prefix-matching" - it matches any URL that *starts with* the source URL.  If you are intending to redirect a specific path (ie. the document root) it would be preferable to use a `RedirectMatch` directive (or mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` - see later) instead. For example:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(index\.html)?$ https://example.com/zc2/
```

This now only matches `/` (or `/index.html`) and redirects to `example.com/zc2/`.

### Using mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) instead

The mod_alias directive (`Redirect` or `RedirectMatch`) in the document root `.htaccess` file is still processed (inherited) when there are other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories (ie. the WordPress `/wp/.htaccess` file).

To avoid the *redirect* in the root `.htaccess` file from ever interfering with your WordPress install then change the mod_alias `Redirect` (or `RedirectMatch`) in your document root `.htaccess` file to a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` instead.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ https://example.com/zc2/ [R=302,L]
```

The mod_rewrite directives in the WordPress `.htaccess` file at `/wp/.htaccess` will completely override the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file (in the document root) - thus avoiding any possibility of conflict. The mod_rewrite directives in the root `.htaccess` file are not even processed.

(Note that this is dependent on Apache's default behaviour, where mod_rewrite directives are not *inherited*.)

Whereas when a mod_alias `Redirect` is used, the mod_alias directive in the parent `.htaccess` file will still be processed (whether it matches or not is another matter) - possible conflict.

If `example.com/` is accessed then the redirect to `example.com/zc2/` still occurs.

Note, that I've used 302 (temporary) redirects above. Change these to 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - only when you have confirmed it's working OK. This is to avoid any potential caching issues.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to use a redirect rule or condition since your simply redirecting the base to a sub folder and therefore those sub folders if linked too wouldn't need th redirect.

*Try something like this in `/.htaccess` file:*

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/zc2/
```

*Then this in your `/WordPress/.htaccess` file:*

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /WordPress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: That redirect would redirect all sub-paths as well.  I don't think it will work.

Comment: Yep your right, Its possible to rewrite the base and then rewrite the base again using htaccess in the WordPress folder since that should overwrite previous rules.